# How to query a string field contains one of array items?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents like this:

```
{
name: '...'
}
```

I want to query for documents which names contains one of:

```
cities = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Of course it's easy to check for exact match like this:

```
col_areas = db['areas']
col_areas.find({'name': {'$in': cities}})
```

I want use `$regex` with each item of cities. How to do that?

I also have tried:

```
for c in cities:
    cities_query.append('/^%s/' % c)

results = col_areas.find({'name': {'$in': cities_query}})
```

Comment: [Regex with in operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#in-expressions)

Comment: @bro-grammer Do I have to change my array to what mentioned there?

Comment: Yes you need to change your array. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177645/combining-regex-and-or-operators-in-mongo) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combining $regex and $or operators in Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25177645/combining-regex-and-or-operators-in-mongo)

Comment: I updated my question. It doesn't worked for me, what's wrong? @bro-grammer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way.
Sample

```
db.col_areas.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'name': 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $or:
                [{ 'name': { $regex: 'a', $options: 'g' } }]
        }
    }
])
```

Customize by yourself.

Comment: you mean I have to repeat each of my array items like this?

Comment: Yep! and change format according to [{ 'name': { $regex: 'a', $options: 'g' } }]